# Using REDUX to store large offline data is a bad idea?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, local-storage, asyncstorage, local-database

I've been using Redux Persist to store large offline data in React Native, but for some reason it's just feels quite slow (on start up).

Using some db would be a better idea?

Comment: How do you define **slow** ? Redux Persist uses `AsyncStorage` of the device, and would take the same time as it would be to get items from it on `rehydration`.

Comment: Maybe the way you manipulate the data is wrong.  A connected component will only re-render when the values it's extracting from state have changed. If you manipulate large parts of the state tree may be a slowdown is noticed.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that Rehydration could definitely cost a little bit. 
But using redux persist won't cost me a lot of memory after rehydrating a ton of data?